# Cannot convert 'Item[]' to 'Item'

Tags: c#

In this question I need to use a method 'AddItem' (found in an other .cs called Inventory) to add each item in my 'StoreStartingItem' array to the store's inventory.

I've tried simply calling the method and running the array through it like this:

```
Inventory.AddItem(StoreStartingItems);
```

However, I keep getting an error `'Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Shop.Item[]' to 'Shop.Item'`.

I've tried changing my 'AddItem' method from using a class parameter to a class array parameter like this:

```
public bool AddItem(Item item)
        {
            if (mItems == null)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
```

To this:

```
public bool AddItem(Item[] item)
        {
            if (mItems == null)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
```

But then I'm getting an error '`An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Inventory.AddItem(Item[])'`'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please learn about the static keyword https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static

Comment: Your parameter name is `item` but you never use it inside your method so why pass it in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears like `AddItem` takes an `Item` but you are passing it an array of `Item` (`Item[]`)

Try this:

```
foreach (var item in StoreStartingItems)
    Inventory.AddItem(item)
```

As mentioned in comments, you may want to read up more on C# and Object Orientated Programming first or follow some tutorials.