# Adding an array to a method

Tags: c#

I have an array of Items called PlayerStartingItems and a method called AddItem. I'm calling the method and then mean to add the array to it so the player has items to start off with.

The code I current have looks like this:

```
Inventory.AddItem (PlayerStartingItems);
```

I keep getting an error *"Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Shop.Item[]' to 'Shop.Item'"*

My method looks like this:

```
public bool AddItem(Item item)
        {
            if (mItems == null)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
```

It uses a class called Item as a parameter and my array uses it as well but to make an array.

**How am I properly meant to add my array to my method in this scenario?**

Comment: Isn’t this basically the same question you already asked https://stackoverflow.com/q/55931669/1806780 and if not, what’s different? And please get a beginner’s book on C# or do a couple of tutorials to understand the syntax of the language as well as how to define variables since this is already the third question of the same method.

Comment: While it is about the same problem, I thought the last question I asked was the wrong question. I'm probably over thinking things and I'm sorry if my questions seemed too similar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot convert 'Item\[\]' to 'Item'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55931669/cannot-convert-item-to-item)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `params` keyword.

That will change your method to:-

```
public bool AddItem(params Item[] itemList) {

    for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++) {

        if (itemList[i] == null) return true;
        else return false
    }
}
```